# laravel subform. submitting data to two different tables

Tags: php, laravel

am working in on a system that is supposed to signup a user and also collect the amount he has contributed and insert into contributions table.

[image]

here is my code:

```
<form class="form" autocomplete="off" action="{{route('benefactors.signup')}}" method="post"  >
```

How can I achieve this? to add both data to benefactors table and contributions table by a single click of the submit button?

Comment: On your controller method where the form is submitting, first insert into one table then insert to the second.

Comment: an example please. am quite a begginer in laravel

Comment: Please show the php code, which you already have, then one can improve on top of it :)

Comment: well I used the idea from @Michel the only difficulty now is getting the benefactors_id inserted into the contributions table. Here is my **AuthController **`
`
Contributions::create([
  'benefactors_id'=>
  'amountNumber'=>$request->input('amountNumber'),
  'paymentMethod'=>$request->input('paymentMethod'),
  'paymentOption'=>$request->input('paymentOption')

]); `   I have created Contributions Model

Comment: First insert into benefactors something like `$ben->save()` Then `$ben->id` should contain the last insert ID so you can put it in contributions table.

Comment: Thanks I used ` $user = User::create([]);

$user->id; `